# Install PostPic Postgres Extension on Windows

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install the postgres extension [PostPic](https://github.com/drotiro/postpic) that allows you to do image manipulation within the database.

On their wiki site they explain installing for Ubuntu, however I installed postgres on windows server 2012.

I read [this blogpost](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/) about installing extensions with visual studio.

The problem is i do not have a visual studio licence.

I am wondering if there is another way for a windows user to install and compile a postgres extension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need another way, Visual Studio Community 2013 (2015) is suitable enough (since it's free). The exact version (2013 or 2015) depends on your PostgreSQL distribution. For instance, EnterpriseDB use VS 2013 to build their releases if I remember correctly. It's better to use the matching Visual Studio (or some other compiler) version in order to minimize the possibility of some non-obvious bugs.

It would be unfair if I didn't mention [MinGW](http://betterlogic.com/roger/2014/10/postgres-extension-building-mingw-woe/), but IMO you should only use it if you're building PostgreSQL yourself for the aforementioned reason.